What does "to eliminate the meddling middlemen of public accountability and free will" mean?
This is a part of the dialogue from the movie "A Scanner Darkly". It's the early part of the movie in which two characters talk about a rehab-like insitution called New Path. The action of the movie takes place in a world in which 20% of the population is addicted to a drug called Substance D. Both of the speakers are users of this drug.

Freck : What do you think about the New Path?
Barris : While it doesn't matter what I think, I kinda have to tip my hat to any entity that can bring so much integrity to evil. I mean, imagine this: a seemingly voluntary, privatized gulag which has managed to eliminate the meddling middlemen of public accountability and free will and wrap it up in a little bow and give it to the public like a gift."

I've got difficulties understanding the part in bold. Does this mean that the middlemen (drug dealers) have public accountability and free will? I.E When they were selling substance D they would be responsible if there was something wrong with the drug and they always had the freedom of choice to sell only the drugs that were pure?
middleman(noun):
a person who buys goods from producers and sells them to retailers or consumers.
–"we maintain value for money by cutting out the middleman and selling direct" (Oxford Languages)

[Keep in mind that's it's not the word middleman I've difficulty with but knowing who possesses the public accountability and free will, and the general meaning of the sentence]

Government oversight.  Accreditation requirements.  If it is "privatized" it could be a place that does not accept private insurance or payments from government health programs, the sort of place that only the wealthy can afford.  A "drug rehabilitation spa" as it were.

Unless there's some further context to justify it, I would not expect sellers of illegal drugs to be called "middlemen of public accountability".  "Middlemen" come between the customer and the product and earn their money by jacking up the wholesale price. They buy wholesale and sell retail. When the customer buys wholesale or gray market, they "eliminate the middleman".  To me it seems like oversight by government and professional accreditation boards are being compared to such middlemen.

The reference to "free will" suggests the attitude of someone who wants to be able to do what he wants without being interfered with by "the nanny state".  But it's sort of crammed into the sentence.  "middlemen of free will" doesn't make much sense.  "of" wouldn't be the proper preposition to use. It works with "of public accountability" which is the opposite of "free will".  Unless the intended meaning is that these middlemen are interposing accountability between free will and the drug.  It's rather garbled.

No one is selling drugs. It's a drug rehab place that is fishy. Not clear in what they do. In other words, they are acting under the radar, away from accountability by public entities.

I agree with @Lambie - this sounds like it is approaching an extermination camp/system. The kind of thing that a Government might approve of, but struggle to justify.

While the existing comments and answers shed light, I think they miss the mark. I think we're to take the construction at face value: the "middlemen" are the concepts that immediately follow, accountability and free will. This is a bit of metaphor or personification. Your dictionary entry says, rightly, that a middleman is "a person," but we can compare words that are normally meant for humans to talk about other things as if they were human, like "love is a cruel mistress" or "fear is a bad teacher." "Middlemen" are an important concept when it comes to business and profit, as they add cost and difficulty to the act of producing and selling. Barris says New Path is "privatized," i.e. run by a company rather than a government, which usually means "for profit." He represents "public accountability and free will" as things that would stand in the way between the company and the "consumer" and eat away at profits or hinder the ease of business.
The whole sentence in question is quite elevated in tone, a bit poetic, choosing very colorful words (like "gulag" instead of the more prosaic "prison"), and "meddling middlemen" is chosen in no small part for its pleasing alliteration.
A working paraphrase might be: [New Path is] a harsh prison that gives the appearance of being a place you can enter (or exit) voluntarily, but they have managed to eliminate those pesky things that stand in the way of their profit: the need for public accountability and their patients' free will, and to present it to the public as if they're doing them a favor.

+1. Does indeed make sense of "middlemen of ... free will" where "middlemen" is metaphor for "complication" or "impediment". So it's an involuntary private for-profit rehab center where the patient has been committed by someone who is paying the bills?

@TimR Without having seen the movie, I'm guessing something of the sort. An attractive front covering some shady and even sinister goings-on. The mention of "gulag" and free will suggest that it's easy to check in, hard to check out.

This is the only way I can understand the quotation. Public accountability is a meddling middleman when it is allowed to be involved in an enterprise. So is free will.

@DavidK Also there’s some sarcasm. The speaker isn’t saying they think these things are meddlesome; they’re giving the idea as if it’s New Path’s words.

@AndyBonner Yes, I think you summed it up perfectly. "And I would have gotten away with it too, if it weren't for you meddling kids!"

I think you have to take the whole of Barris' statement into account.
The way I read it is  as follows (your interpretation may differ as I've not seen the film).
He starts by saying "New Path are entity that can bring so much integrity to evil." In other words, whilst they appear to be a force for good, they are evil. He goes on to explain that, by being a private company, they can supress anyone "meddling middlemen of public accountability and free will" who tries to have oversight and hold them accountable for their actions. He likens their operation to a secret Russian prison, a "privatized gulag".
The phrase "middlemen … of free will" also ties in with "seemingly voluntary" which implies that the inmates may not have had any choice and are forcibly detained.
The middlemen are not drug dealers, but probably human rights activists of some sort trying to look into the way New Path operates.

Yes, most rehab places fall under rules of accountability to some government agency. Here, they seem to do whatever they please. Middlemen can be any private organizations or individuals who keep tabs on places like this.

(spoiler)
The key is that "New Path" produces Substance D, which produces addicts, which  must then at some point become its clients.
The language in the quote refers to this in a way that is both cynical and metaphorical.
First, it assumes that rehab organizations (or maybe organizations in general) are typically corrupt, but face difficulties in accomplishing their evil goals, because their actions are mediated by requirements for public accountability and the free will of their customers.  Then it comments on how the New Path, by secretly producing its own desperate customers, and then performatively "helping" them, manages to dodge both of these impediments.
